# Запуск сервера ботов для Telegram на OpenSSL

Tags: telegram-bot, openssl

Хочу запустить сервер ботов для телеграмма с самоподписанным сертификатом.

1. Получил токен у BotFather (https://core.telegram.org/bots).
2. Создаю сертификат. (https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed).

   > ```
   > openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout YOURPRIVATE.key>
   > -x509 -days 365 -out YOURPUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE"
   > ```
3. Запускаю сервер:

   > ```
   > openssl s_server -accept 88 -key YOURPRIVATE.key -cert YOURPUBLIC.pem
   > ```
4. Посылаю хук с сертификатом:

   > ```
   > curl -F "url=https://URL:88/bot" -F "certificate=@YOURPUBLIC.pem" https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setWebhook
   > ```

Ответ:

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
```

5. К серверу подключается Телеграмм, сервер выдает ошибку:

   > ```
   > 139690177754952:error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:s3_pkt.c:1257:SSL alert number 46
   > ```
6. Проверка:

   > ```
   > openssl s_client -connect URL:88
   > ```

Клиент подключается нормально, данные передаются.

Подскажите,

1. С какими параметрами запускать openssl s_client так, чтобы он использовал сертификат, который я посылаю Телеграмму. То есть эмитировал работу Телеграмма и выдавал тут же ошибку.
2. Что исправить в моих действиях, чтобы Телеграмм подключался к серверу и передавал данные?

Comment: У меня подобная проблема с сертификатом, если есть возможность, [отпиши сюда пожалуйста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618914/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-telegram)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблемы требовалось указать в поле CN сертификата имя сервера к которому будет подключаться Телеграмм.