# Запуск сервера ботов для Telegram с OpenSSL

Tags: php, apache2, openssl, heroku, telegram-bot

Уже несколько дней пытаюсь запустить сервер для бота телеграм,точнее 3 сервера:

1. Сервер на Heroku, тестовый, на нем замечательно работает, веб хук устанавливается, бот отвечает.
2. Сервер в корпоративной сети, конфигурированием сети занимался не я, но порт 88 проброшен, по внешнему ip и данному порту в браузере по https на него захожу. Установлен Apache, устанавливал, настраивал я, доступ ко всему есть, самоподписной сертификат генерил я.
3. После неудачной попытки второго варианта, предположил что проблема в сети. Для этого дома, оплачиваю статический ip, пробрасываю порт, устанавливаю linux, apache, настраиваю ssl, захожу по данному ip из внешки на свой сайт по https, работает, веб хук устанавливаю, результат ОК, но бот не отвечает.

В логах /var/log/apache2/access.log инфа о конектах только из браузеров, информация о том что телеграм пытался подключиться отсутствует.

В ем может быть проблема? 
Перелапатил весь интернет, делаю все по описанным схемам, как  в доках телеграма, так и других. Делаю примерно так [Запуск сервера ботов для Telegram на OpenSSL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460030/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-telegram-%D0%BD%D0%B0-openssl)

Comment: `telegram` не должен "пытаться подключиться" к вам, ваш бот должен обращаться к `telegram api` и сам отслеживать сообщения

Answer (score 2):

В моем случае нужно было правильно сгенерить ключи:

> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout apache.key -x509
>   -days 365 -out apache.pem -subj "/C=RU/ST=Krasnodar/L=Krasnodar/O=./CN=IP адрес моего сервера, который
>   доступен из вне"

И правильно установить webhook:

> curl -F "url=https://ip:port/" -F "certificate=@apache.pem"
>   https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setWebhook