# Проблема с сертификатом в Telegram

Tags: ssl, openssl, ispmanager, telegram

Использую сервер с ISPmanager 5.8, ОС Ubuntu Server 16.04.
Порт 443 открыт, доступ извне есть. Генерирую ключ такой командой:

> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout tele.key -x509
>   -days 365 -out tele.pem -subj "/C=RU/ST=Krasnodar Krai/L=Tuapse/O=telegram/CN=tele.zhirov.su"

Далее, что я делаю... Через Sublime открываю tele.key и tele.pem, копирую код в ISPmanager при создании сертификата[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В доменном имени сайта прикрепляю этот сертификат - всё успешно. Браузер видит сертификат.

Далее - отправляю телеграму tele.pem ключ:

```
<form action="https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕНБОТА/setwebhook" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="url" value="https://tele.zhirov.su/bot.php">
        <input type="file" name="certificate">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить данные">
    </form>
```

В ответ приходит:

> {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}

Проверяю командой getWebhookInfo, получаю такое на выходе:

> {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://tele.zhirov.su/bot.php","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"last_error_date":1485273410,"last_error_message":"SSL
>   error {336134278, error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify
>   failed}","max_connections":40}}

Так же пробовал отправлять и такой командой через терминал:

```
curl -F "url=https://tele.zhirov.su/bot.php" -F "certificate=tele.pem" "https://api.telegram.org/botТОКЕНБОТА/setwebhook"
```

Что делать, я уже не знаю... Может сертификат не правильно добавляю или отправляю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Проблема решена!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256898/telegram-bot-on-openssl)

В общем, всё заключалось в том, что я не указал знак @ в отправке сертификата:

```
-F "certificate=tele.pem"
```

Нужно было сделать так:

```
-F "certificate=@tele.pem"
```

Будьте внимательны!)

Answer (score 0):

Телеграмм добавил возможность самоподписных сертификатов. Прикольно. Раньше такого счастья не было. Я делал через бесплатный сертификат Let's Encrypt, который кстати отлично работает и в браузерах, в отличии от самоподписных

https://habrahabr.ru/post/270273/

**UPDATED**
Так должно взлететь

```
function requestParams(array $data) {
    $has_resource = false;
    $multipart = [];

    array_walk($data, function (&$item) {
        is_array($item) && $item = json_encode($item);
    });

    foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
        $has_resource |= is_resource($item);
        $multipart[] = [
            'name' => $key,
            'contents' => $item,
        ];
    }

    if ($has_resource) {
        return [
            'multipart' => $multipart,
        ];
    }

    return [
        'form_params' => $data,
    ];
}

$file = '/home/test/certificate.pem';

$data = [
    'url' => 'https://tele.zhirov.su/bot.php',
    'certificate' => fopen($file, 'r'),
];

/**@var \GuzzleHttp\Client $client */
$response = $client->post("/bot{$APIKEY}/setWebhook", requestParams($data));
$result = (string)$response->getBody();
```

Comment: Да, я знаю на счёт Let's Encrypt. Только не смогу новые зарегистрировать, у меня лимит на домен уже есть.

Comment: @azhirov1991 если мне не изменяет память, там исключительно временные лимиты, причем довольно позволительные, кроме того, там можно указать alternative name, и это будет считаться за отдельный домен

Comment: Ну я сейчас попробовал отправить запрос - ругается на лимит всё равно.